# Connecting events using socket in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-modules, monodevelop

very new to nodejs and looking for some help here.
I've three files index.html, server.js and client.js.
I've created a socket to run my app in real-time, which is to display message in the div tag with id="add" entered by the user.
User enters the message in the input field with id="element", and the message should be displayed when the button with id="send_data" is clicked on.
Any help would be appreciated.
About to start my new journey wth new js.
I'm using only js in client-side and not any framework at all
The message can be seen by everyone even owner:
Here is my code
index.html:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <p><input class="form-control" id="element" type="text" value="Les parties"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="send_data">Ajouter</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div id="add"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is the server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);



app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});



io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('message',  => {
    io.emit('message', "Hello word");
    console.log('displaying message')
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And finally here is client.js

```
let url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
 var socket = io();
 var socket = io.connect(url)
 let counter = 0;
let add = document.getElementById("add");
let element = document.getElementById("element")

 add.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    add.innerHTML = element.value;
    socket.emit('message', element.value);
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that based on your code you need to put the client.js in a public folder. I assumed that you have your node_modules, package.json and so on in place. So in your **public/client.js**

```
let url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
 var socket = io();
 var socket = io.connect(url)
let add = document.getElementById("add");
let btn = document.getElementById('send_data')

 btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    add.innerHTML += `<li>${element.value}</li>` ;
    socket.emit('message', element.value);
 })

 socket.on('message', (m) => {
    alert("message from the server: "+ m)
 })
```

In your **server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);


app.use('/static', express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});



io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log("socket connected: ", socket.id)
  socket.on('message', (message) => {
    // emit message from the server
    io.emit('message', "Hello word");
    console.log(`message ${socket.id}: `, message)
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

In your index.html. You would have to import socket.js from the client. In this context, you cannot import it from the node_modules as it will be in the browser running. You can bundle it using webpack or other bundler before it is served. Since we are not using webpack to do this. You will need to fetch it from the cdn like so

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <p><input class="form-control" id="element" onclick="me" type="text" value="Les parties" /></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="send_data">Ajouter</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div id="add-cont">
            <ul id="add"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-cPwlPLvBTa3sKAgddT6krw0cJat7egBga3DJepJyrLl4Q9/5WLra3rrnMcyTyOnh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./static/client.js"> </script>
```

[image: on the client]

[image: code structure]